# How to get Rdd values that exists in array?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have `Rdd[(Int, Double)]`
 and an `array[Int]` and i want to get a new `Rdd[(Int, Double)]` with only those `Int` that exist in the array too.

E.g if my `array` is  `[0, 1, 2]` and my `rdd` is `(1, 4.2), (5, 4.3)`, i want to get as output `rdd` only the `(1, 4.2)`

I am thinking about using `filter` with a function that iterates the array, do the comparison and  returns `true/false` but i am not sure if it is the logic of `spark`.

Something like:

```
val newrdd = rdd.filter(x => f(x._1, array))
```

where

```
f(x:Int, y:Array[In]): Boolean ={
   val z = false 
   for (a<-0 to y.length-1){
         if (x == y(a)){
            z = true
            z}
       z
```

}

Answer (score 1):

//Input rdd

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,4.2),(5,4.3)))
```

//array, convert to rdd

```
val arrRdd = sc.parallelize(Array(0,1,2))
```

//convert rdd and arrRdd to dataframe

```
val arrDF = arrRdd.toDF()
val df = rdd.toDF()
```

//do join and again convert it to rdd

```
df.join(arrDF,df.col("_1") === arrDF.col("value"),"leftsemi").rdd.collect
```

//output Array([1,4.2])

Answer (score 0):

```
val acceptableValues = array.toSet
rdd.filter { case (x, _) => acceptableValues(x) }
```

Comment: That seems easy, but i get  `Type mismatch, expected: (Int, Double) => Boolean, actual: Boolean`.

Comment: This probably has to do with the version of Scala. I modified the answer to require less inference from the compiler.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rdd.filter(x => Array(0,1,2).contains(x._1)).collect.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
(1,4.2)
```